# Using activity with drawer, scrolling toolbar, tabs and different fragments

Tags: android, toolbar, android-design-library, coordinator-layout, nestedscrollview

I'm looking for best practices when it comes to the following pretty common setup:

What I'm currently doing is:

My Main Activity has a navigation drawer and a Toolbar. 
When you click on one of the list items inside the drawer a fragment is loaded under the toolbar. Some fragments have their own tabs inside using viewpager ect.

I would like to make use of the material functionalities like hiding the toolbar while scrolling ect. It is no problem to get it done.
But there is a problem when only some of your fragments would like to make use of the scrolling toolbar. Using a normal Scrollview does solve the problem if you can add an additional margin at the bottom, but once you have a keyboard it will mess up as the scroll is wrong. Using a nestedscrollview works but does scroll the toolbar.
So how can I avoid the scrolling toolbar when my activity holds the toolbar and some fragments that scroll should make use of it and some not?

Is the architectural design wrong? Another thing I thought is to have the different toolbars inside of each fragment... but they have to share the same navigation drawer so you have to create and add the ToggleButton each time? Is it the right approach ? Should I go that path? I'm not convinced and would like to have the opinion of somebody more experienced then me. What's the best solution in this case.

Appreciate your help!
Cheers

EDIT:
Main Activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_first"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/owner_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/addicon"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/owner_main_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="xxx.Classes.Misc.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawerhost" />
```

Comment: can you please add your code.

Comment: I added my Activity layout code

Comment: is there a a behaviour to set on my nestedscrollview to avoid scrolling toolbar? something to use instead of the appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour.

just need a nestedscrollview that does not scroll my toolbar

Comment: currently I have a workaround... I use normal scrollviews for the fragments that should not scroll my toolbar and I have to take care of the height and the scroll position when the keyboard comes up. It's the same thing with the floating button. The positioning of the floating button is wrong when using it directly inside a fragment... so I had to use it inside the activity instead that has the coordinatorlayout and the toolbar

Answer (score 1):

I am also Using navigation drawer and tool bar please import project from [this link](https://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest) 
 And try to understand how to use navigation drawer and tool bar using fragment

Comment: thank you for the link. Will directly take a look at it - and then come back to you

Comment: your project does not cover my use case... there is no scrolling toolbar nor does the drawer change fragment (it does change tab)